# Cloud Foundry plug-in is not installable into pulse managed eclipse (due to missing joda time osgi bundle)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pulse, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to install [Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse Indigo (3.7)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cloud-foundry-integration-eclipse-indigo-37)
Through the eclipse marketplace into my pulse managed eclipse.

During the "marketplace, Installing Software" phase, I'm getting the error:

`Could not find repositories containing the following artifacts: [osgi.bundle,org.joda.time,1.6.0.v20081202-0100]`

It seams that the people from genuitec and the vmware/spring people a playing some ping pong here.

genuitec says: 
they a reference the bundle, so they have to provide it
vm ware/spring says: it's a optional bundle, so it's an error in pulse

pulse/genuitec people:

> The best course of action would be to go to the spring people and let them know they are depending on something that is not available via an update site. You could also let them know that this would break usage in regular eclipse as well.

source: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cloud-foundry-integration-eclipse-indigo-37

spring/vmware people:

> The org.joda.time dependency is an optional one from one of the core Spring Framework libraries. So you DON'T NEED it to install or run STS. Don't know why Genuitec Pulse is complaining about it, maybe its not recognized as optional? A bit more detailed error message could help here.

source: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-116040.html?

or here
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?116040-STS-2-8-0-released

Is there a way to get this to run?
Could I drop in joda time osgi bundle somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joda time plugin happens to be available from this update site:

```
http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/e3.4/
```

It *is* an optional dependency and so Pulse shouldn't be failing when it's not around, but adding this update site should make the dependency available.

Comment: I added that update site, and Jed at the pulse support forum told me to add add in addition "http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/e3.4" and install "SpringSource Tool Suite Cloud Foundry" from there. This works. Pulse Forum thread: http://www.poweredbypulse.com/forums/showthread.php?1588-Cloud-Foundry-is-not-installable-due-to-missing-joda-time-osgi-bundle